# Replacing conditional with something?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, polymorphism, conditional-statements, strategy-pattern

I have the following nested if clause, I was wondering if I, by applying some pattern, can simplify it?

The code checks to see if it needs an authorizationStartDate, and if it does, but does not have it, returns true.

I've considered the Strategy Pattern, the  "Replace conditional with polymorphism" method, the Specification Pattern and various others, but I haven't found anything which I liked.

```
private bool IsMissingAuthorizationStartDate(ApplicationStatusData data)
    {
        if (data.ApplicationStatus == ApplicationStatusType.ApplicationApproved)
        {
            if (data.ApplicationPurpose == ApplicationPurpose.New)
            {
                if (data.ProductStatus?.ProductStatusType == ProductStatusType.ApplicationForNewProductReceived)
                {
                    if (data.ApplicationTypePesticide == ApplicationTypePesticide.Authorisation ||
                        data.ApplicationTypePesticide == ApplicationTypePesticide.ProvisionalAuthorisation ||
                        data.ApplicationTypePesticide == ApplicationTypePesticide.MutualRecognition ||
                        data.ApplicationTypePesticide == ApplicationTypePesticide.Derogation ||
                        data.ApplicationTypePesticide == ApplicationTypePesticide.DispensationPreviousAssessment ||
                        data.ApplicationTypePesticide == ApplicationTypePesticide.ResearchAndDevelopmentPurposesExperimentOrTestProgram ||
                        data.ApplicationTypePesticide == ApplicationTypePesticide.ResearchAndDevelopmentPurposesExperimentOrTestProgramKnownProduct ||
                        data.ApplicationTypePesticide == ApplicationTypePesticide.ParallelTradePermit ||
                        data.ApplicationTypePesticide == ApplicationTypePesticide.Copy
                        )
                    {
                        if (!data.AuthorizationStartDate.HasValue)
                        {
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (data.ApplicationPurpose == ApplicationPurpose.Renewal)
            {
                if (data.ProductStatus.ProductStatusType == ProductStatusType.ProductAuthorised)
                {
                    if (data.ApplicationTypePesticide == ApplicationTypePesticide.ReAuthorisation ||
                        data.ApplicationTypePesticide == ApplicationTypePesticide.ParallelTradePermit ||
                        data.ApplicationTypePesticide == ApplicationTypePesticide.Copy
                        )
                    {
                        if (!data.AuthorizationStartDate.HasValue)
                        {
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // else
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: An immediately obvious problem is that the method does not do what it says on the tin. If it did what it said on the tin it would be one line long: `return !data.AuthStartDate.HasValue;`  A more general problem is that you've encoded business policy into source code in a way that cannot be programmatically manipulated. If your program is about policy evaluation then make a graph of policy objects that know how to evaluate whether the policy is met or violated.

Comment: So the question I would be concerned about here is not how to make the code less complicated; the code must necessarily be as complicated as the policy it represents. Rather I would be concerned about what is going to happen when the policy changes, as inevitably policies do.

Comment: @EricLippert: Exactly, my worry is that if/when these rules change, it will be hard to decode what kind of situations the different forks in the conditional represents. Right now, the business rules are described in an excel sheet, and it's not trivial to find out which situation requires a start date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern I would use here is just encapsulation. The nesting here is hard to follow, and worsened by the equality comparisons. If possible, instead of exposing the raw field, try encapsulating the *intent*.

e.g. Instead of `if (data.ApplicationPurpose == ApplicationPurpose.Renewal)` try extending `ApplicationStatusData` with a property like

```
bool IsRenewalApplication 
{
 get 
 {
  return this.ApplicationPurpose == ApplicationPurpose.Renewal;
 }
}
```

so your code reads cleaner, with more expression: `if (data.IsRenewalApplication) { ... }`

Particularly where you have that massive if this or that or that or that, put it under a well-named property like `IsInterestingPesticide`.

If you can't change `ApplicationStatusData` for some reason, you can do the same thing with member functions that return Boolean values, expressing the same intent.

HTH!

PS, You might even want to encapsulate the entirety of the nested-ifs into a single concept. Then you'd just have 2 Boolean tests before you return false.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you might want to take a look at the next level up in the code, the fact its returning a boolean indicates this is being used in a conditional by something else.

That said I do usually like the [chain of responsibility](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/chain_of_responsibility) pattern for this sort of thing. But I personally wouldn't have it return a boolean, I'd have the responsible object perform an action if it was determined to be responsible for that type of data (i.e. Another level up).

Just an option for you to consider, there isn't a hard and fast rule for this kind of thing.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't really answer to your question which was about design pattern, but that might still interest you.
You could rewrite your method like that.

First two arrays:

```
private ApplicationTypePesticide[] typePesticidesNewPurpose
    = new ApplicationTypePesticide[]
{
    ApplicationTypePesticide.Authorisation,
    ApplicationTypePesticide.ProvisionalAuthorisation,
    ApplicationTypePesticide.MutualRecognition,
    ApplicationTypePesticide.Derogation,
    ApplicationTypePesticide.DispensationPreviousAssessment,
    ApplicationTypePesticide.ResearchAndDevelopmentPurposesExperimentOrTestProgram,
    ApplicationTypePesticide.ResearchAndDevelopmentPurposesExperimentOrTestProgramKnownProduct,
    ApplicationTypePesticide.ParallelTradePermit,
    ApplicationTypePesticide.Copy
};

private ApplicationTypePesticide[] typePesticidesRenewalPurpose
    = new ApplicationTypePesticide[]
{
    ApplicationTypePesticide.ReAuthorisation,
    ApplicationTypePesticide.ParallelTradePermit,
    ApplicationTypePesticide.Copy
};
```

Then your previous method becomes:

```
private bool IsMissingAuthorizationStartDate(ApplicationStatusData data)
{
    return data.ApplicationStatus == ApplicationStatusType.ApplicationApproved
        && (IsMissingAuthorizationStartDatePart2(data, ApplicationPurpose.New,
                ProductStatusType.ApplicationForNewProductReceived, typePesticidesNewPurpose)
            || IsMissingAuthorizationStartDatePart2(data, ApplicationPurpose.Renewal,
                ProductStatusType.ProductAuthorised, typePesticidesRenewalPurpose));
}

private bool IsMissingAuthorizationStartDatePart2(ApplicationStatusData data,
    ApplicationPurpose purpose, ProductStatusType statusType,
    params ApplicationTypePesticide[] typePesticides)
{
    return (data.ApplicationPurpose == purpose
        && data.ProductStatus.ProductStatusType == statusType
        && statusType.Any(st => data.ApplicationTypePesticide == st)
        && !data.AuthorizationStartDate.HasValue);
}
```

Note: you can remove the `params` keyword if you always call the method like in this example.
You should also think about rename the part2 method.